# Why do language-variations of the same site not appear in the User's info and do they apply to some benefits?

Tags: discussion

Let's imagine that I have 350 Rep in the spanish SO site and 20 in this one.

As you probably know, when you reach 200, you are given 100 in every site (Site association bonus). Does this apply to language-variations of an SE site? Would I get 100+ points here?

And, why don't this variations show up in your user's information page? Does only the highest rep of the language-variations appear?

Comment: Have you read [What is the association bonus, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 4):

There does not exist such a thing as a "language-variation" of a site on the Stack Exchange network. What you call "variations" are separate sites, just in their respective languages. This means that everything that applies to normal sites of the network applies to them too. For the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work) it means that **yes**, if you become eligible for the bonus on one of those sites, you will get the bonus. Every other association bonus rule also applies.

As for the user information page and "showing up", by which I presume you mean the *profile* page and the "Communities" list respectively, the "language-variation" sites follow the same rules for the abovementioned reason of being first-class citizens of the network, meaning:

- the list is ordered in decreasing order of earned reputation;
- only a small subset of non-hidden communities is shown (say thanks to Stack Exchange's UI team);

You have, at the time of this writing, 380 reputation points on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17089665/) proper, 141 on [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/123375/), 113 on [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/107135/), 111 on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/95375/), 103 on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/455777/) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users/961378/), and 101 from the association bonus on Stack Overflow en español. With only 5 slots available in the list, it leaves us with:

| # | Community | Rep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stack Overflow | 380 |
| 2 | Travel | 141 |
| 3 | Blender | 113 |
| 4 | Worldbuilding | 111 |
| 5 | Unix & Linux | 103 |